# Still having trouble ending a thread

Tags: android

I got some answers, and Went ahead and tried the following:

```
01 import android.app.Activity;
02 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
03 import android.os.Bundle;
04 import android.os.Handler;
05 import android.os.Message;
06 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
07 import android.media.AudioManager;
08 import android.content.Context;
09 import java.lang.Runnable;
10  
11 public class CanvasDrawingActivity extends  Activity   {
12      
13     private static final int FIRE = 0;
14     private int initVolume = 0;
15     private Handler handler;
16     private MyCanvas v;
17     private MediaPlayer mp;
18     private AudioManager am;
19     private MyRunnable r;// this is our custom runnable!
20  
21     @Override
22     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
23         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
24          
25         am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
26               
27             // this method gets the current volume setting for music
28             initVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
29               
30             // this method sets the volume for music | the 100 is the volume. you can put there either initVolume or whatever value you want
31             am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
32          
33         mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.siren_1);
34          
35         makeHandler();
36         v =new MyCanvas(this);
37         setContentView(v);
38         r = new MyRunnable();// this needs to create a new MyRunnable
39         new Thread(r).start();
40         mp.setLooping(true);
41         mp.start();
42     }
43     private void makeHandler()
44     {
45         handler  = new Handler(){
46  
47             @Override
48             public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
49                 switch(msg.what)
50                 {
51                 case FIRE:
52                 {
53                     v.invalidate();
54                     break;
55                 }
56                 }
57             }
58              
59         };
60          
61     }
62     private class MyRunnable extends Runnable {// you had this in the wrong spot...
63             private boolean doRun = true;
64              
65             @Override
66             public void run(){
67             while(doRun)
68                 handler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRE);
69                 }
70         public void stopThread(){
71             doRun = false;
72         }
73     }
74     protected void onpause() {
75         super.onpause();
76         mp.stop();
77         r.stopThread();
78         finish();
79     }
80     protected void onfinish() {
81         mp.stop();
82         r.stopThread();
83         finish();
84     }
85          
86     }
```

I'm getting an error that runnable cannot be the superclass. Specifically that the type runnable cannot be the superclass of MyRunnable; a superclass must be a class.

Then in the onpause and onfinish it gives the error: Te method stopThread is undefined for the type runnable. This happens even when extends is changed to implements.

I also tried:

```
01 Runnable MyRunnable = new Runnable(){
02        
03          
04         private boolean doRun = true;
05          
06         @Override
07         public void run(){
08             while(doRun)
09                 handler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRE);
10         }
11         public void stopThread(){
12             doRun = false;
13         }
14     }
```

I tried also:

```
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable \\etc
```

that clears up the runnable issue but causes my

```
r = new MyRunnable();
```

and

```
r.stopThread();
```

to be errors still which say:
the `stopThread is undefined for the type runnable, and Type mismatch cannot convert from CanvasDrawingActivity.MyRunnable to Runnable.`

Can anyone help me out here. I feel like this is a good option to end the thread, but again, I get some impassable errors...

Comment: are you sure its onpause or [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) also refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204012/why-isnt-the-thread-stopping)

Comment: For some reason it likes to make those lower case. It is onPause(), but the formatting changed that.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an anonymous class, the only methods you can access from outside the class itself are those declared in its supertype. In your case, any code outside the class can only call the run() method, since that's all that's defined for a Runnable. The solution is to declare an explicit class, which is what you tried to do with MyRunnable.

The error messages, though, suggest that you didn't get it quite right. In particular, the "type mismatch" error says that MyRunnable does not implement Runnable. That message must have come from code different from what you posted. Also, apparently whatever object you are trying to use to call stopThread is known to the compiler at that point only as a Runnable, not a MyRunnable.

On a separate note, once you get past the compiler errors, you are not going to be happy with how this runs. You will be sending empty FIRE messages as fast as the cpu can produce them. You need to slow that down a bit, perhaps by calling Thread.sleep() with an appropriate delay.

Comment: I declared r, which I'm using for the runnable as: private MyRunnable r; So it should register as a myRunnable but doesn't. I'm not sure why. As for adding the Thread.sleep, is that something like Thread.sleep(incriment) or : thread.sleep(2000) to get it to slow down. I am using this to alternate a color on a screen, which I want to flash fairly fast, but not insanely so. I appreciate the help, and any more insight you may have.

Comment: I'd like to still hear your opinions on the thread.sleep and how to use it appropriately. I'd love for this to perform great out the gate.

Comment: Thread.sleep(35) will pause the loop for 35 milliseconds. That's about 30 frames a second, which is about at the limit of what the eye can follow. Many animations do very well with 10 fps, or 100 mSec between frames. If you're flashing a color, once every couple of seconds should be fine. You'll need to surround the call to sleep with a try/catch block for InterruptedException. That gets raised if interrupt() is called on the sleeping thread.

Comment: Thanks Tedd. That is helpful info. I have a book I was reading that suggested 2000. I'm glad I asked. so if I try: try{ Thread.sleep(100); } catch(InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); } Will that work? The only example I can find is structured that way. I'd put that in my run() method then? This should make the whole method take a short break? I just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: I did try this:  private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
      
  
  private boolean doRun = true;
  
  @Override
  public void run(){
   while(doRun)
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(FIRE);
   try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  public void stopThread(){
   doRun = false;
  }
 }     But it didn't appear to work....My cpu still hits 100% usage. I'm wondering if I implimented it correctly or if I should increase the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles fine for me:

```
private MyRunnable r;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    r = new MyRunnable();// this needs to create a new MyRunnable
}
private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private boolean doRun = true;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
    public void stopThread(){
        doRun = false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    r.stopThread();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    r.stopThread();
}
```

You should bear in mind @Ted Hopp's comments regarding the performance of this solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting that. That's virtually identical to what I have in my current code. The issue is that I'm getting this: the stopThread is undefined for the type runnable, and Type mismatch cannot convert from CanvasDrawingActivity.MyRunnable to Runnable. I'm not sure why mine doesn't compile...

Comment: I rearranged the placement of a few of my declarations and POOF it worked! I dunno why, they should have worked where they were, but hey we're in business. Thanks for the support!